# How to deal with suspected abuse or neglect

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mandatory Reporters](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/mandatory-reporters)

Inevitably, people will post about concerning situations. For example, 
[When you don't think (grand)children are getting the care they need](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/what-to-do-about-grandchildren-who-need-help-to-have-well-what-they-need)

What is the site's stance on reporting suspected child neglect or abuse? One possibility is to have a flag for it, or to add educational info in a reference on the site.

It's a tough situation, because in child endangerment cases, there is sometimes preceding documentation. And in other cases, there is concern, but after a more thorough investigation no problem is found.

I think it may be important to connect users with local, national, and perhaps global reporting guidelines and resources, such as, the National Child Abuse and Neglect Hotline: 1-800-4-A-CHILD (1-800-422-4453).

http://www.childwelfare.gov/systemwide/laws_policies/statutes/manda.cfm

http://www.dshs.wa.gov/ca/safety/abusereport.asp

Answer (score 1):

[This related question](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/mandatory-reporters) is 1½ old and is still the current state of affairs: This isn't something we can make a general rule for. It will have to be a case-by-case decision.

Your best action is to **use the flag function** ("needs ♦ moderator attention") and let the moderators handle it. The (volunteer!) moderators will probably defer the matter to the staff of Stack Exchange (the company behind the website).

By the way, I think your response to the question you are referring to is excellent!